# Running GUI from stand-alone JFormDesigner

Tags: java, swing

I've built program in JFormDesigner stand-alone, saved it and when i run it nothing shows. What do i need to edit or type in order for it to show? 
Thank you.

```
public class Something extends JFrame {
    public Something() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        // JFormDesigner - Component initialization - DO NOT MODIFY  //GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
        // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Vanja Banic
        label1 = new JLabel();
        button1 = new JButton();
        button2 = new JButton();

        //======== this ========
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        //---- label1 ----
        label1.setText("Something");
        contentPane.add(label1);
        label1.setBounds(0, 0, 585, 39);

        //---- button1 ----
        button1.setText("text");
        contentPane.add(button1);
        button1.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(95, 160), button1.getPreferredSize()));

        //---- button2 ----
        button2.setText("text");
        contentPane.add(button2);
        button2.setBounds(new Rectangle(new Point(285, 160), button2.getPreferredSize()));

        { // compute preferred size
            Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension();
            for(int i = 0; i < contentPane.getComponentCount(); i++) {
                Rectangle bounds = contentPane.getComponent(i).getBounds();
                preferredSize.width = Math.max(bounds.x + bounds.width, preferredSize.width);
                preferredSize.height = Math.max(bounds.y + bounds.height, preferredSize.height);
            }
            Insets insets = contentPane.getInsets();
            preferredSize.width += insets.right;
            preferredSize.height += insets.bottom;
            contentPane.setMinimumSize(preferredSize);
            contentPane.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        }
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(getOwner());

    }


    // Generated using JFormDesigner Evaluation license - Vanja Banic
    private JLabel label1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    // JFormDesigner - End of variables declaration  //GEN-END:variables
}
```

I know it now lacks main() and i am not sure what to write in it to show program. 
This is example that would show 1 label and 2 buttons.

Comment: Please put a code snippet to see what is wrong/right.

Comment: Edited. Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `setVisible(true);` to the end of your initComponents() method:

```
private void initComponents() {
    // your mentioned code

    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: DUH, done that with other ones but not with one from JFormDesigner.. Thank you!

Comment: If that solved your issue, can you accept the answer?